# Некорректное отображение :checked при выборе через JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

HTML:

```
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="admin" value="t" id="adminTrue"> Да
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="admin" value="f" id="adminFalse"> Нет
</label>
```

JavaScript

```
$('#infoUser').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
    var modal = $(this)
    var admin = button.data('user-admin')

    if (admin == 't') {
        modal.find('input[id="adminTrue"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
    } else {
        modal.find('input[id="adminFalse"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
    }
})
$('#infoUser').on('hide.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var modal = $(this)
    modal.find('input[name="admin"]').removeAttr('checked');
})
```

Браузеры отображают не правильно выделенные `radio`, хотя есть анализировать код Firebug, то в DOM все правильно меняется.

Здесь можно посмотреть полный код с примером:
http://codepen.io/ArsenBespalov/full/eNOwRy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема первая. У вас переменная `admin` undefined. Почему? Все из-за вашей невнимательности. У кнопки в примере есть атрибут `data-user-id` и нет атрибута
 `data-user-admin`, который вы пытаетесь прочитать.

Проблема вторая. Невозможность повторной установки атрибута checked можно побороть следующим образом:

```
if (admin == 't') {
  modal.find('input[id="adminTrue"]').trigger('click');
} else {
  modal.find('input[id="adminFalse"]').trigger('click');
}
```

Протестировал несколько раз. С таким подходом выбранная радиокнопка всегда корректно отображается.

Answer (score 0):

Устанавливать свойство `checked` нужно через `prop`

`$().prop('checked', true);`